# Does not recognize TextField on Different Views within Same ViewController

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have 3 UIViews on one ViewController. Each UIView has its own TextFields. When I call the following code, it only works on the first UIView

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
    //first UIView
    if (textField === usernameRegisterTextField) {
        passwordRegisterTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else if (textField === passwordRegisterTextField) {
        emailRegisterTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else if (textField === emailRegisterTextField) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    } 
    // second UIView
    else if (textField === usernameLoginTextField) {
        passwordLoginTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else if (textField === passwordLoginTextField) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    } 
    // third UIView
    else if (textField === emailForgotTextField) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach textfield delegate to ViewController.

```
self.textfield1.delegate = self;
self.textfield2.delegate = self;
self.textfield3.delegate = self;
```

**OR**

From storyboard; Right click drag from textfield to yellow circle on top of the ViewController and select delegate.

Comment: thank you! I totally forgot to add the delegates after the first UIView